# TFS 2010 and Outlook 2013 integration

Tags: tfs, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

How can I convert my `Outlook tasks` to `Tfs Task workitem`s I've found this [Outlook Tfs Addin](http://outlooktfsaddin.codeplex.com/), but it seems it doesn't support Outlook 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TeamLook](http://www.teamsystemsolutions.com/teamlook/features/microsoft-outlook-integration.aspx) supports Outlook 2013 with TFS 2010 and can convert Outlook tasks to work items.

Answer (score 1):

Wit-It 2013 does look promising however the current installation seem to be having some basic issues in at least the SCRUM template - like being unable to copy from the [Description] field to the [Acceptance Criteria] field with ctrl-x. So it's very difficult to move the information around before creating the WorkItem.

Answer (score 1):

[TMO](http://gotmo.co.uk) Seems to do this fairly straightforward. I like the no clutter UI and that they give you 6 months to try out the product.

Answer (score 0):

[Wit-It 2013](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2015/04/01/wit-it-2013-create-work-item-from-email/) supports Outlook 2010 and 2013. It only supports converting Outlook emails, not tasks like you requested. Since tasks may start as an email, this allows skipping a step in the process.

It's free and  supports creating various work item types in TFS.

Comment: Is there a version for outlook 2016?

Comment: Hello @soandos I don't see any other version. However, you can ask the author via the link to the tool.