# How to automatically create TFS work item from emails

Tags: tfs, process, agile, ticket-system

Does Visual Studio Online or TFS on premise offer the functionality to create work items from received emails?

I would like clients to be able to email through requirements and issues without having to navigate around the UI.

Comment: Related [TFS 2010 and Outlook 2013 integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090978/tfs-2010-and-outlook-2013-integration)

Comment: anything for tfs 2015?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' nope. Use Zendesk or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about having them just log work items directly, instead of going through email. [Work Item Only View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668124.aspx)

Other email option is [TeamCompanion](http://www.teamcompanion.com/features/working_with_mails_5/#0)  ... noticed this on an old post from [Brian Harry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2009/03/17/tfs-outlook-add-ins.aspx), it don't know anything about it but looks like has Outlook 2013 support.

Comment: That TeamCompanion link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to create work items from Outlook objects. You can write a quick VSTO add in to do this yourself (happy to help there if you like) or as Gern mentioned you can use one of the many products in the market. I'd recommend [TMO](http://gotmo.co.uk) but fair disclaimer - I am the founder of this product. Which by the way also means that I am always around to answer questions directly should anyone need me to :)

Comment: How to use the TMO? can you help me with some documentations?

Comment: Hi Moanvel, there are plenty of short videos on the site https://gotmo.co.uk The best way is to download the product and click the buttons. It is fairly easy to get started with. Especially now with the Auto Pilot mode (http://gotmo.co.uk/blog/auto-pilot) TMO will automatically create work items without any manual input! Do check it out.